# Envoy - redis clusters via aggregate cluster not working, authorization is missing "(error) NOAUTH Authentication required"

Tags: redis, envoyproxy

As part of fallback purposes, we trying to setup 2 redis databases in our envoy proxy and make one of them as primary.
I am using the latest envoy proxy image and their aggregate cluster setup and it looks like i cant inherit the redis authorization params properly.

EXAMPLES:
After while we succeeded setting up 2 listeners against 2 clusters and everything working properly :)
for example:
listeners -
[image]
clusters(the second cluster is similar) -
[image]
looking good:
[image]
now i try to setup the fallback cluster included both as envoy wrote in the docs:
[image]
the only part I am not 100% sure is here, the listener part for the new aggregated cluster(I assumed it is the same as before):
[image]
ok so now the issue is that I cant do my commands on the databases and it looks like it's not passing the "auth_password"?
[image]

please if you need any more information i will happily add more but the setup is very minimalistic and simple so i am not sure how deeper i can dive here but i will try.

i am using envoyproxy/envoy:v1.28-latest
something wrong with my setup? i am doing something wrong? there is an issue with the aggregated cluster and the redis authorization?

thank you very much!